# Failure(new RuntimeException("Some Failure")) vs Failure(throw new RuntimeException("Some Failure")) in Scala

Tags: scala, exception

I was trying my hands on *Try* in scala for handling exceptions. I was wondering how *Failure* works? When I try the below expression it evaluates to a *Failure* type:

```scala
val someFailure = Failure(new RuntimeException("Failure String"))
println(someFailure)   // OUTPUT: Failure(java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure String)
```

But, when I throw an exception inside *Failure* it does not evaluates to *Failure* type:

```scala
val someAnotherFailure = Failure(throw new RuntimeException("Failure String"))
// throws RuntimeException - java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure String
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `new RuntimeException("Failure String")` evaluates to a proper value whilst [throw expression](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#throw-expressions) `throw new RuntimeException("Failure String")` does not evaluate to a value but instead aborts evaluation. The throw expression executes before it is passed in to `Failure.apply` so

```
val someAnotherFailure = Failure(throw new RuntimeException("Failure String"))
```

is analogous to

```
val temp = throw new RuntimeException("Failure String") // aborting happens before attempting to pass it to Failure.apply
val someAnotherFailure = Failure.apply(temp)
```

because the argument to `Failure.apply` is passed in by-value. However if you have a look at signature of `Try.apply`

```
object Try {
  def apply[T](r: => T): Try[T] =
    try Success(r) catch {
      case NonFatal(e) => Failure(e)
    }
}
```

note how argument is passed [by-name](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/by-name-parameters.html) `r: => T` which means throw expression is evaluated **after** it is passed in to `Try.apply` so

```
val someFailure = Try(throw new RuntimeException("Failure String"))
```

is analogous to

```
lazy val temp = throw new RuntimeException("Failure String") // throw expression is not yet evaluated
val someFailure = Try.apply(temp) // : Try[Nothing] = Failure(exception = java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure String)
```